# Ringing issue in DC load circuit simulation in LTSpice

Tags: mosfet, ltspice

I am working on a DC load circuit and have put together a simple configuration based on templates available online. As you can see in 3rd image attached, I am noticing a small ringing in the load circuit measured at R1 which is a current sense resistor.
I am assuming its being generated from the OPAMP not being able to stablise quick enough and so I tried different random solutions like adding 10 pF capacitor between MOSFET base and ground however I am unable to completely get rid of the ringing.

Can anyone suggest a methodological approach to stablise the opamp and remove this ringing?

Thanks,

1. Schematics
   [image: Schematics]
2. Full output Vsingal vs I(R2)

[image: Full graph]

3. Ringing zoomed
   [image: Ringing]

Edit: Final schematics with added RC filter on 2nd stage opamp to filter out ringing. Adding to original post in case anyone's looking for similar solution:

[image: Final Schematics]

Comment: R5 should be much lower ... (100 Ohm or 0 ?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an additional tweak that will help ensure stability.

[image]

The output in my simulation above is more-or-less accurate if V3 is current-limited. In reality U2 will be destroyed if V3 is too low in source impedance.

You should limit the input voltage to U2 to >= 0V. If it goes negative by more than a few hundred mV and the current is limited you'll see the phase reversal in my simulation, and if it's not limited you'll probably damage the chip.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It seems the 1nF capacitor and changing R3 to 680 ohms did the trick. I am now getting full current resolution without any ringing. Regarding the V3, I am only using sine wave to test the characterstics of variable DC input. In real world it will be 0 - 5VDC and thus my input reference will never go in negative.

Comment: Also, may I ask the theory behind the capacitor and resistors (R2, R3 and C1)  and how's it helping eliminate the ringing ? My understanding is that the three elements create a RC filter which elimitated the harmonics (ringing). Is my assumption correct ?

Comment: @Prashant Capacitive loading (such as the gate in the MOSFET with only 1Ω in series effectively) can destabilize most op-amps. The series resistor makes it much worse (the op-amp itself has poorly documented ~100Ω output resistance).  By adding significant phase-shift to the feedback you're (at a minimum) decreasing phase margin. The theory behind in-loop compensation such as I used is covered in [this](https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/ask-the-applications-engineer-25.html) AD  paper, but note that it's somewhat guesswork since the output resistance is not well known.

Comment: To test this (including in simulation), you should use square waves which are much more likely to excite oscillation or ringing than sine waves.

Comment: I feel like I'm learning more from just being on this forum then my entire 4 yrs of engineering. Thanks a lot for clear , crisp and real-world explaination for this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what you should have as outputs ... when changing your R5 to 100 Ohm.

[image]

Here is the "response" with a square wave at 10 kHz.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Replacing R5 to 100 ohms did help a bit.